# ¿Cómo conocer el texto de un input y mostrarlo en un mensaje?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, popup

Tengo un popUp que por medio de una función en javascript me permite crear una tabla que tiene un control tipo input (textbox), en este control debo digitar ciertos datos y mostrarlo en un alert, al escribir los datos en el input(textbox) el mensaje (alert) no se muestra y no se puede confirmar si esta o no tomando los datos que están en dicho control, he utilizado parte de este código.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>celda 1</td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>3.000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div><input id="uno"> </input>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>celda 2</td>
        <td>celda 3</td>
        <td>2.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("table tbody tr").change(function() {
      var total = $(this).find("uno").text();
      alert(total);
    });
  </script>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hwXN.jpg)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es que al ingresar un dato en el campo de cédula y al cambiar de control me muestre un mensaje donde me aparezca el dato que esta escrito en dicho campo (cédula).

Comment: No sera que el div no esta cargando bien el demas codigo
??

Comment: El evento `change` se dispara cuando el evento `blur` se dispara, es decir cuando te enfocas en el elemento, no cuando sufre cambios el contenido de este. Prueba usar el evento `keyup`  `$('table tbody tr').on('keyup', function()....`

Comment: ¿Has realizado la misma pregunta varias veces?

Answer (score 2):

con jquery lo pudes hacer de esta manera:

```
   $(function(){
       $('.cualquierNombre').focusout(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
       })
   })
```

solo tienes que colocar una clase en tu texbox

ejemplo completo: https://jsfiddle.net/madaver1980/n9yj9ohd/

espero te ayude, saludos!